# How do you know when to specify parameters for git pull and git push?

Tags: git, repository

Usually I just use `git pull` and `git push` without any parameters, but I noticed in some instructions parameters like "master" and "origin" are used. How do you know when to use these parameters and when not to?

Comment: It looks like almost all of your questions can be avoided by doing a little groundwork first. Use `--help` and a quick search for your issue before posting, to avoid being a [Help Vampire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem), specifically `Are they obviously just waiting for some poor, well-intentioned person to do all their thinking for them?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you syncing your local repo with only a single remote, then you rarely need to use additional options and the default values (see [Bryce's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39045071/1314743)) work fine.

There are two cases where you want to deviate from the defaults:

- You want to sync with some remote other than your default upstream. In this case, you use `git pull repo_of_other_dev` or `git push …` to sync the current branch with the other repo.
- You use different names for your branches. In this case, you need to explicitly define *which* branch to pull from / push to.

  For `push`, the syntax is `git push repo_of_other_dev master:feature-a` to push your master branch to the `feature-a` branch.

  For `pull`, the syntax is `git pull repo_of_other_dev feature-a`. `git pull` always integrates into your current branch (whatever that is). `git push` can push arbitrary branches, not only the current.

Answer (score 1):

## Finding default values for git pull:

### Use `git pull --help`.

### Default Values:

> Default values for `<repository>` and `<branch>` are read from the "remote" and "merge"
>          configuration for the current branch as set by git-branch(1) --track.

---

### Context:

> NAME
>
> `git-pull - Fetch from and integrate with another repository or a local branch`
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> `git pull [options] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]`
>
> `<repository>` should be the name of a remote repository
>
> ...
>
> `<refspec>` can name an arbitrary remote ref ... usually it is the name of a branch in the remote repository.`
>
> ...

Now we find that below this last bit are where the default parameters are listed.

## For git push:

### Use `git push --help`.

also read the help function. Help functions are very helpful for all git functions.

> ...If the configuration is missing, it defaults to **origin**.